# Mac Catalyst app: how to close a window without terminating the app?

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I'm developing an app by using Mac Catalyst.

When user has closed the window on Mac version, the app is terminated.

It was possible to change this behavior in Cocoa by using:

```
applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed
```

method or by setting NSSupportsAutomaticTermination to NO in plist file.

How can I get the same in a Mac Catalyst app?

Comment: Well, by my findings even injecting at AppKit level in macCatalyst mode, the `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` callback is not used. They terminate directly via private document controller. The only possible to do is prevent termination by `applicationShouldTerminate`, but in this case window is not closed.

Comment: @asperi yes. I also tried similar workarounds but still didn't have a chance to make it working. By the way, how do you inject Appkit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've discussed the problem with Apple technical developer support. After a long discussion, they accepted that this is a bug on Apple side. It's escalated to the engineering team.

UPDATE:
Apple Engineering team has provided the following information regarding this issue and it worked for me:

We were able to prevent the quitting behavior by adding NSSupportsAutomaticTermination = NO to info.plist

Comment: Thank you! I hope, that there will be soon a lot of bugfixing and improvements to SwiftUI and Catalyst. Please let us know, if there is a final solution, I will need it as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Makes no difference here either.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

## This answer is not working, see the comments.

**EDIT END**

This is only possible, if you activate "Supports multiple windows":

[image]

My thoughts, why it is like this: macOS differentiates between applications and windows. So if your application can open only one window, closing that will tell macOS to close the application.

PS: I experienced some bugs in the "supports multiple windows" mode. I hope, that they will be removed soon.

Comment: This is also what I'd expected but not. When you enabled this option, the app icon is not visible in the dock and for sure, this is not the expected behavior.

Comment: Can you try it with a new clean project? For me it works.

Comment: I tried. When I enabled multiple window support in a clean macCatalyst project, when the user has closed the window and then clicked on somewhere on the screen, the app icon is not visible anymore on the dock.

Comment: Aaah, you're right, the icon will be gone, when you click somewhere else, sorry, I didn't check that. Then please forget my answer, I think that is something that Apple has to fix in Catalyst. Maybe you should file a bug.

Comment: I've opened a support request but no valid anser until now. Thanks for your replies

Comment: I'm not a macOS developer (iOS and used to be Windows too), so please forgive me for wondering out loud... as a workaround, could you (a) say the app supports multiple windows, then (b) throw up and minimize an "empty" window? By empty I'm thinking anything from an invisible window that only the OS sees to an visible window with a "close app" button - an yes, a minded window fits in between these. Absolutely it's a workaround, but until something better comes along from Apple, would this be technically feasible?

Comment: @dfd: I had the same idea, but I couldn't find a way to hide the window. Unfortunately requesting a new `UIScene` will instantly open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, maybe someone is still looking for this :)

1st we need to have access to AppKit. In this link you can find a good explanation of how to do it, as well as some sneak peek on the next step. [link](https://crunchybagel.com/disabling-the-mac-zoom-maximise-button-in-catalyst/)

Once we have an AppKit bundle ready, and read the explanation of how to disable the zoom button on the window (on the link above), we are ready to do what we actually want; which is to avoid the app termination when the Close button is clicked. For that we will simply hijack the Close button and tell it to do what we need...

```
- (void) tweakWindowButtons
{
    NSArray *windows = NSApplication.sharedApplication.windows;
    
    NSWindowCollectionBehavior behavior = NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenNone;
    
    for (NSWindow *window in windows) {
        [window setCollectionBehavior:behavior];
        
        //-- Hijack close button action
        NSButton *button = [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
        [button setTarget:self];
        [button setAction:@selector(closeButtonAction)];
        
        button = [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton];
        [button setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

- (void) closeButtonAction
{
        NSApplicationActivationPolicy policy = NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory;
        
        //-- hide app icon and window
        NSApplication.sharedApplication.activationPolicy = policy;
    }
}
```

To bring the view back, set the policy to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`

BTW, I'm assuming we also have a statusbar icon that will be working as an anchor to the app.