# How to keep an app from quitting after closing its window on Mac Catalyst?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiapplicationdelegate, mac-catalyst

I started a sample iOS app in order to explore SwiftUI; at some point I thought enabling Mac support would be a fun thing try, and surprisingly, I have good result with little to no additional code.

Testing the app on the Mac, I notice the app quits once I close its window, which is not the way most apps work.

Trying to use `applicationShouldHandleReopen` is not an option since `NSApplicationDelegate` is not possible for Catalyst, I was not able to find a counterpart either in `UIApplicationDelegate` or `UISceneDelegate`, and I was not able to find anything on this topic on Apple's documentation.

What's the proper way to implement the traditional Mac app behavior(†) on a Catalyst app?

*(†) Traditional mac app behavior: When the app window is closed, the app icon remains in the doc and if you click it the apps window reappears again*

Comment: Isn't this `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed`? Or is catalyst special because it comes from the iOS world?

Comment: also if you don't have multiple windows, this _is_ the right behavior

Comment: see for example Calendar or System Preferences

Comment: Thank you for your comments; the delegate you mention belongs to `NSApplicationDelegate` which is not available on Catalyst.

Comment: I'd be keen to know this, too. The only thing I came across is a [tweet from Simon B. Støvring](https://twitter.com/simonbs/status/1200834427221352448?s=21) that addresses this using swizzling.

Answer (score 2):

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61054790/8247429)

To summarize, do one of the followings

- **Using project file**

  1. Go to your project file, click on your target
  2. Go to "General" and then go to "Deployment Info"
  3. Go to "Status Bar Style" and then enable "Supports multiple windows"
- **Using `Info.plist`**

  1. Expand "Information Property List"
  2. Expand "Application Scene Manifest"
  3. Set "Enable Multiple Windows" to "YES"

[Another answer in the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141201/8247429) recommends setting `NSSupportsAutomaticTermination` to `NO`. This also works, but I am not sure if messing with `NSSupportsAutomaticTermination` brings you "surprises".